# RxJava Buffer - List of List

Tags: rx-java, reactive

```
public class RxBufferMasterList {

    private List<ArrayList<Integer>> mMasterList;
    RxBufferMasterList() {
        mMasterList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    }

    public void execute() {
        Observable.fromIterable(getList()).buffer(3).subscribe(new Observer<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                Log.i("Reactive","onSubscribe");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull List<Integer> integers) {
                Log.i("Reactive","onNext: "+integers);
                mMasterList.add((ArrayList<Integer>) integers);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Log.i("Reactive","onError: "+e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.i("Reactive","onComplete: "+mMasterList);
            }
        });
    }

    private List<Integer> getList() {
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        return Arrays.asList(intArray);
    }
}
```

So, I would like to get rid mMasterList.add functionality.
I think its possible to get list of list from Observable itself. Which operator should be used for that  purpose?

Comment: Why do you `buffer`? You could simply use `toList` on the unbuffered sequence to get a full list.

Comment: @akarnokd can you please elaborate?

Comment: Can you please elaborate why are you using `buffer`? Also how were you trying to use `mMasterList`? Applying [`toList`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList--) on your source directly will result in a complete list which then you can [subscribe for](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#tolist).

Comment: its possible in kotlin... val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")    
    println(numbers.windowed(3)). Wanted to know....is it possible to do the similar job in RxJava.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve here. Windowed(3) creates a sliding window, which is `buffer(3, 1)` for RxJava. Also windowed crerates individual lists and does not combine them back into one big list.